# Types of conversion not supported by the compiler

Tags: c++

So far, I could only find the types of conversion supported by the C++ compiler which are user-defined types to basic type, basic type to user-defined type, and one user-defined type to another user-defined type. My question is what are the types of conversions that are not handled by the C++ compiler.

Comment: You have a list of conversions that are supported. The conversions not supported would be the inverse of that. See also the C++ specification. If you want a more specific answer, it will depend which compiler you're using and which flavor of C++ you're compiling.

Comment: can you give an example? not sure what the question is.

Comment: "what are the types of conversions that are not handled by the C++ compiler."  Answer: anything not in the C++ standard. For example converting a class type to a physical object.

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean what kind of conversions are not checked at compile-time.

`reinterpret_cast` conversions happen at run-time, which is why they are dangerous and may crash your program:

```
struct CustomClass {};

int main()
{
    CustomClass c = {};
    int x = 0;
    x = *(reinterpret_cast<int *>(&c)); // undefined behaviour, may e.g. crash
}
```

In contrast, the compiler would not allow you to convert a `CustomClass` to an `int` with a `static_cast`:

```
struct CustomClass {};

int main()
{
    CustomClass c = {};
    int x = 0;
    x = static_cast<int>(c); // compiler error
}
```